# jQuery .serialize() form Data

Tags: jquery

I have the following form with some input fields:

```
<form id="saveUserForm">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Login:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="d_login" value=""/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="d_password" value=""/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="d_email" value=""/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Role:</td>
            <td><select id="d_role"></select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>MAC:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="d_mac" value=""/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>HWID:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="d_hwid" value=""/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>TV Model:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="d_tvmodel" value=""/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

I am trying to serialize the form data to a string.
Something like this:

```
var formData = $("#saveUserForm").serialize();
alert(formData);
```

But the formData string is empty. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Where & How are you using `$("#saveUserForm").serialize();`?

Comment: input need attribute name to be serialized

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Serialize uses name attribute and not ids.

```
<input type="text" id="d_login" name="logn" value="hii"/>
```

try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Ss9Y/)

Comment: Omg, what a mistake. Thank you all guys :)

Comment: Can you mark the answer as correct if you don't mind?